# Best way to integrate PayPal donate in Android?

Tags: android, paypal

I am developing an app. Now I need to integrate PayPal donate in my Android app. I did a lot of searching, and I got two methods. But I don't know the difference between these methods and which is the best method. What is the best way?

**Method 1:**

*[PayPal Android SDK With Multiple In-App Payment](http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/10/paypal-android-sdk-with-multiple-in-app.html)*

**Method 2:**

*[PayPal Integration in Android](http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2012/09/paypal-integration-in-android.html)*

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 is more beautiful and easy for the user, a better HIM.
And more understandable.